# Calculating elapsed time between two dates, gives different results in different devices

Tags: android, time, calendar

Im trying to get the time elapsed from a specific date (in millis)

In some devices I get the correct result
however, in other devices I get wrong result

here's the code that i use:

```
public static void timeElapsedFromDate(long workingDate) 
{
    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - workingDate;

    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
    long diffMinutes = diffSeconds / 60;
    long diffHours = diffMinutes / 60;
    long diffDays = diffHours / 24;
    long diffWeeks = diffDays / 7;
    long diffMonth = diffDays / 30;
}
```

Isn't it the way to measure time?

thanks!

Comment: Are all the devices set in the same time zone?

Comment: That or do they have the same time?

Comment: @LazyNinja the funny thing is that chaning the timezone isn't affect the System.currentTimeMillis(). i.e If I change the timezone in a device that gives me good results, I still get good result after changing the timezone

Comment: Is the time correct on all the devices you're testing? I'm not asking about the timezone--I'm asking about the correctness of the time itself.

Comment: So all months are now 30 days? Use the Calendar or Date objects.

Comment: which attribute you get different value while using different devices ? i mean diffSeconds or any other ?

Comment: _chaning the timezone isn't affect the System.currentTimeMillis()_


It should not! Because once the system time is right, changing time zone (i.e. the display time) does not change the answer you get from `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `diffMonth` formula asks to be improved: from Feb 1st to Mar 1st it is usually 28 days, but one month. From Sep 1st to Sep 31st it is 30 days, but less than 1 month.

More subtle question regarding diffDays: isn't it 1 day between 10 PM and 10 AM next morning?

Finally, how different devices can give different results: [System.currenTTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) returns *the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.* Even if the clock on all devices is correct, they may have different Time Zone settings.

Comment: One should always calculate time in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getElapsedTimeInDays(Date start,Date end){
    int days=(int)(start.getTime()-end.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24);
    return days;
}
public int getElapsedTimeInHours(Date start,Date end){
    int hours=(int)(start.getTime()-end.getTime())/(1000*60*60);
    return hours;
}
public int getElapsedTimeInMinutes(Date start,Date end){
    int minutes=(int)(start.getTime()-end.getTime())/(1000*60);
    return minutes;
}
public int getElapsedTimeInSecunds(Date start,Date end){
    int scunds=(int)(start.getTime()-end.getTime())/(1000);
    return secunds;
}

//Then you can use the codes like this:
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, hh:mm");
Date start = df.parse("2012-01-12, 09:35");
Date end = new Date();//this will be the curent date;

int day = getElapsedTimeInDays(start,end);
```